# Does threading a lot leads to thrashing?

Tags: multithreading, cpu-usage

Does threading a lot leads to thrashing if each new thread wants to access the memory (specifically the same database in my case) and perform read/write operations through out its lifetime?

I assume that this is true. If my assumption is true, then what is the best way to maximize the CPU utilization? And how can i determine that some specific number of threads will give good CPU utilization?

If my assumption is wrong, please do give proper illustrations to let me understand the scenario clearly.

Comment: One can only cut pieces of a pie so thin..

Comment: @user2864740 , so thin... !!! please explain your view

Comment: Hmm, threads don't accomplish much when they query a database, they are just bogged down waiting for the dbase server to supply the results.  At best you'll piss of a DBA when you take an unfair share of the dbase server's resources and he'll throttle you.  Perf cannot be predicted, only measured.

Comment: @HansPassant, in that case do you think using multiple DB in different places would cut down some waiting time? Will the situation be same if I use files to manage the data which each thread will use.?

Comment: Files are the same problem, you only have a single disk so threads are just waiting to get their turn to read from it.  In general *very* detrimental to throughput, a disk doesn't like to be jerked around.   With the disk read head jumping back and forth, seeks are by far the most expensive thing you can ever do with a disk.

Comment: @HansPassant, Then I think running the operation serially one by one rather than by using threads will be a better choice, since every thread will need DB access.

Comment: Of course modern hard drives have internal RAM caches to minimize the latency caused by seeking; and modern OS's use any otherwise-unused RAM for caching as well, to minimize seeks, and finally, flash drives don't have any moving parts so for them "seeks" are really no-ops that don't take any time.  So the drive-heads-seeking-back-and-forth performance problem may be less severe these days than it used to be, depending on the system you are running on.

Answer (score 2):

Trashy code causes trashing. Not thread. All code is ran by some threads, even the main(). Temp objects are garbage collected the same way on any thread.

The subtle part is when each thread preloads its own objects to perform the work, which can duplicate a lot of same classes. It's usually a small sacrifice to make to get the power of concurrency. But it's not trash (no leak, no deterioration).

There is one exception: when some 3rd party code caches material in thread locals... You could end up caching the same stuff on each thread. Not really a leak, but not efficient.

Rule of thumb for number of threads? Depends on the task.

If the tasks are pure computation like math, then you should not exceed the number of non-hyperthreaded cores.

If the job is memory intensive along with pure computation work (most cases), then the number of hyperthreaded cores is your target (because the CPU will use the idle time of memory access for another core computations).

If the job is mostly large sequential disk i/o, then you number of threads should be not to much above the number of disk spindle available to read. This is VERY approximative since the disk caches, DMA, SSD, raids and such are completely affecting how the disk layer can service your thread without idling. When using random access, this is also valid. However, the virtualization these days will throw all your estimates out the window. Disk i/o could be much more available than you think, but also much worse.

If the jobs are mostly network i/o waits, then it is not really limited from your side; I would go with about 3x the number of cores to start. This multiplier is simply presuming that such thread wait on network for 2/3 of its time. Which is very low in practice. Could be 99% of its time waiting for nw i/o (100x). Which is why you see NIO sockets everywhere, to deal with many connections with fewer busier threads.

Answer (score 2):

No, you could have 100's of idle threads waiting for work and not see any thrashing, which is caused by application working set size exceeding available memory size, so active pages need to be reloaded from disk (even written out to disk to when temporary variable storage needs saving to be relaoded later).

Threads share an address space, having many active leads to diminishing returns due to lock contention.  So in the DB case, many processes reading tables can proceed simultaneously, yet updates of dependant data need to be serialised to keep data consistent which may cause lock contention and limit parallel processing.

Poorly written queries which need to load & sort large tables into memory, may cause thrashing when they exceed free RAM (perhaps poor choice of indexs).  You can increase the query throughput, to utilise CPUs more, by having large RAM disk caches and using SSDs to reduce random data access times.

On memory intensive computations, cache sizes may become important, fewer threads whose data stays in cache and CPU pre-fetches minimise stalls, work better than threads competing to load their data from main memory.